# Primefaces tabView: embed text near title attribute of p:tab

Tags: view, jsf-2, customization, primefaces, tabbed

Perhaps,somebody faced such a problem,looks like specific one and concerning *Primefaces* `tabView` component.
There is tabbed view comments module and I would like to display comments number within tab,like this:

[image]

How is it possible to embed text if `<p:tab>` generated dynamically and contains a lot of HTML sub-elements (`ul` , `li` etc.)?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add output in the tab title.

```
<p:tab title="Comments #{myBean.number}">
</p:tab>
```

Bean would look something like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

  private int number;

  public MyBean() {
    this.number = 5;
  }

  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public void addComment() {
    setNumber(number + 1);        
  }

}
```

[image]

Update Comments total with ajax:

```
<h:form>                                
  <p:tabView id="tabs">
    <p:tab title="Comments #{myBean.number}" >
      <p:commandButton value="Add Comment" 
           action="#{myBean.addComment}" update="tabs"/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab" ></p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

I couldn't get update to work correctly on the tab level but updating the entire tabView works.

Comment: Hi Mark.Good idea if non-ajax, i have ajax and need immediate update, so i specify <p:tab title="Comments #{myBean.number}" id="someId"> where someId is transformed to href value of rendered p:tab.Got error when click on tab:uncaught exception: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.Anyway, good idea and i looking into it